# ASP.NET MVC Session Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

So basically I have a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomUserData>`. The thing I want to do is to add SessionId/UserData pairs to this dictionary when the user logs in and remove it from dictionary when user logs out or session times out. What is the best practice for doing this. I was trying to implement this using global.asax events but I could not find any suitable one.

Comment: You *could* use the in-built [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) functionality, but you should consider whether you really need to store complex objects in-memory instead of in a database.

Comment: I agree with RGraham. You can also consider to simply use cookies with a short lifetime. You are notified that a session ends only if the session datas are stored in-memory (in the w3wp.exe process).

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are using MVC, I assume you use some standard authentication provider. So just find you responsible for authentication controller, and in set you dictionary in appropriate cotroller actions, not in global.asax events.

`Global.asax` is used for whole app global events, like app initialization.

Comment: and in that case where should this Dictionary be located in?

Comment: That depends on your goal, session not shared between users, cache is shared for all users, db if you want to store it for a certain period of time. Plenty of ways you can store it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using some already existing authentication provider. [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx) for example, or the new [ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx).

But if you really want to go with the dictionairy, you could create a BaseController which contains this dictionary, every controller deriving from this BaseController will have access to it:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomUserData> _users;
    protected ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomUserData> Users
    {
        get
        {
            if (_users == null)
            {
                _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomUserData>();
            }
            return _users;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can derive from this controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use session state? YOu could just add an extra check to make sure the user is logged in?

Comment: I need to keep sessions and userdata for reason. There are guys outside my application which are connected to me by some API and I need to track sessions associated with users to supply them some information.

Comment: SO you're already keeping session state, but store (in db or other) for another application to also see this data? Not sure I understand?

Comment: those other application dont have access to same db that I have. I mean the only way they contact with me is through that API. basically through a WCF service. and I have to supply them a token for each session and keep everything synced